# Estimating Endogenous vs Exogenous growth models

Tags: economic-growth, production-function, endogenous-growth, growth-accounting

Exogenous economic growth models (mostly those that take technological progress, or change in TFP as exogenous and random) are rather easy to estimate econometrically.

But how about endogenous growth models?

---

I've looked at a few papers with endogenous growth models, but they look more like small instances of CGE (computable general equilibrium) models than simple production functions with restrictions and assumptions.

---

My question is: what's the basic difference in parameter estimation of those models?